# Like button on Hebrew website makes Gibberish instead of the language

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, hebrew

I have got a website (Wordpress), that is in Hebrew. Made in UTF-8.

The problem is that sometimes, when one of the users share on Facebook the shared data is in Gibberish and not in Hebrew....

http://readbooks.co.il/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99-%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%99/#.TvZB5Dh7gqA

Please help.

Comment: What's the problem? The link is URL-encoded, when I hover over it, I see nice Ivrith in the status bar (disclaimer: I don't know it well enough to say whether it's really nice). Do you want the URL to be displayed readable?

Comment: The problem is not in the URL, but in the content that is shared... For some reason on some pages the content is not in Hebrew but in Gibbrish....

Comment: Maybe the pages where it comes out as gibberish are/claim to be encoded in latin1 or some other non-UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you mean by "share of Facebook", since **Like Button** just using **OpenGraph** tags existing on your page and you have URL in exactly this representation as `og:url`.

You using Facebook `sharer.php` to share content on Facebook which placing URL as `caption` field for feed stories (without ability to change that), `caption`-s for feed stories can't be provided via `og:tags`, but it may be provided by using [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

BTW, It's ok for URLs to be like this, this is a proper way to encode 'em so every user can visit your site no matter how archaic his browser.

Comment: Nop, actually found. My hebrew had invalid chracters, since it was cut not multi byte safe, OPENGRAPH was not working with it.